# Access <%def>s in included mako file

Tags: python, flask, mako

I am currently implementing a feature in a Flask application. I have multiple parent mako files which includes the same child mako file.

```
# parent.mako
...
<%def name="title()">${page_title}</%def>
<%include file="child.mako"/>
...


# child.mako
<h1>${title()} Discussion</h1>
```

Basically, I am trying to pass the `title()` into the child.mako. However, the def block does not seem to render in the included file. Can anyone else give me a solution? I hope it will be simple and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to import namespace into your child template file:

```
<%namespace name="title_namespace" file="parent.mako"/>
```

then you would be able to use it like:

```
${title_namespace.title()}
```

I hope it will help you.